# How can I send multiple commands' output to a single shell pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, exec, jq

I have multiple pipelines, which looks like:

```
tee -a $logfilename.txt | jq string2object.jq >> $logfilename.json
```

or

```
tee -a $logfilename.txt | jq array2object.jq >> $logfilename.json
```

For each pipeline, I want to apply to multiple commands.

Each set of commands looks something like:

```
echo "start filelist:"
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/*
```

or

```
echo "start wget:"
wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_1.zip 2>&1
wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_2.zip 2>&1
```

and the output from those commands should all go through the pipe.

---

What I've tried in the past is putting the pipeline on each command separately:

```
echo "start filelist:" | tee -a $logfilename | jq -sRf array2object.jq >>$logfilename.json
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/* | tee -a $logfilename | jq -sRf array2object.jq >>$logfilename.json
```

but in that case the JSON script can only see one line at a time, so it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: BTW, I'd **really** suggest putting a shebang on your JQ script and marking it executable. Easier to pipe through `json_log_s2o` than `jq -s -R -f json_log_s2o.jq` -- and that way all the information about how said jq script is supposed to be executed is embedded in the script itself. (And if someday you rewrote it from jq to another language, you wouldn't need to change its callers)

Comment: That makes good sense, reducing parameters and code modularity, will implement as suggested.

Comment: ATM, I am testing different pipelines with different jq programs to handle different command inputs

Comment: BTW, you're now showing the same pipeline twice (and have the backticks present as quoted literals, making them look like they're part of the surrounding code). I'd argue that this is actually *less* useful / more misleading about what you're trying to do than the prior formulation.

Comment: Ah, maybe this needs to be more obvious e.g. `string2object.jq` and `array2object.jq`. The intent is to run different pipelines with different jq  programs for processing different command inputs for similar or different json outputs. Perhaps you're right that this confuses the objectives, not sure.

Comment: Ahh; yes, that does clarify quite a bit. I'd still kill the extra backticks, since they imply that you want any stdout that somehow *didn't* get redirected to be string-split and glob-expanded into a command and then executed.

Comment: Updated pipeline examples to look more shebang like, but thought retaining the `jq` might help for clarity ?

Comment: In general, command names don't have extensions on UNIX: You run `ls`, not `ls.elf`. This means also that you have the flexibility to rewrite in a different language in the future without breaking all software that uses your program (or keeping an outdated and misleading name). Python provides another informative example: Your *modules* end in `.py`, but when you have setuptools create a command-line entry point (ie. a wrapper for such a module), that wrapper has no extension.

Comment: ...so, as long as invocation is `jq array2object.jq`, the extension is appropriate; but if it's an executable file with a working shebang (in this case, `#!/usr/bin/env jq -sRf` -- it's not guaranteed that more than two arguments can be passed as part of the shebang, and the `f` needs to be last), then the name can (and arguably should) just be `./array2object` (or, if it's in the PATH, `array2object`).

Comment: That makes sense, delving deeper to look at shebangs and invocations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Portable Approach

The following is portable to POSIX sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
die() { rm -rf -- "$tempdir"; [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }
logfilename="whatever"

tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"/fifodir.XXXXXX) || exit
mkfifo "$tempdir/fifo" || die "mkfifo failed"

tee -a "$logfilename" <"$tempdir/fifo" \
  | jq -sRf json_log_s2o.jq \
  >>"$logfilename.json" & fifo_pid=$!
exec 3>"$tempdir/fifo" || die "could not open fifo for write"

echo "start filelist:" >&3
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/* >&3

echo "start wget:" >&3
wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_1.zip >&3 2>&1
wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_2.zip >&3 2>&1

exec 3>&-         # close the write end of the FIFO
wait "$fifo_pid"  # and wait for the process to exit
rm -rf "$tempdir" # delete the temporary directory with the FIFO
```

---

#### Avoiding FIFO Management (Using Bash)

With bash, one can avoid needing to manage the FIFO by using a process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfilename="whatever"

exec 3> >(tee -a "$logfilename" | jq -sRf json_log_s2o.jq >>"$logfilename.json")

echo "start filelist:" >&3
printf '%s\n' "$PWD/*" >&3

echo "start wget:" >&3
wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_1.zip >&3 2>&1
wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_2.zip >&3 2>&1

exec 3>&1
```

---

#### Waiting For Exit (Using Linux-y Tools)

However, the thing this *doesn't* let you do (without bash 4.4) is detect when `jq` failed, or wait for `jq` to finish writing before your script exits. If you want to ensure that `jq` finishes before your script exits, then you might consider using `flock`, like so:

```
writelogs() {
  exec 4>"${1}.json"
  flock -x 4
  tee -a "$1" | jq -sRf json_log_s2o.jq >&4
}
exec 3> >(writelogs "$logfilename")
```

and later:

```
exec 3>&-
flock -s "$logfilename.json" -c :
```

Because the `jq` process inside the `writelogs` function holds a lock on the output file, the final `flock -s` command isn't able to *also* grab a lock on the output file until `jq` exits.

---

#### An Aside: Avoiding All The >&3 Redirections

In either shell, the below is just as valid:

```
{
  echo "start filelist:"
  printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/*

  echo "start wget:"
  wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_1.zip 2>&1
  wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_2.zip 2>&1
} >&3
```

It's also *possible*, but not advisable, to pipe a code block into a pipeline, thus replacing the FIFO use or process substitution altogether:

```
{
  echo "start filelist:"
  printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/*

  echo "start wget:"
  wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_1.zip 2>&1
  wget -nv http://web.site.com/downloads/2017/file_2.zip 2>&1
} | tee -a "$logfilename" | jq -sRf json_log_s2o.jq >>"${logfilename}.json"
```

...why not advisable? Because there's no guarantee in POSIX sh as to which components of a pipeline if any run in the same shell interpreter as the rest of your script; and if the above *isn't* run in the same piece of the script, then variables will be thrown away (and without extensions such as `pipefail`, exit status as well). See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more information.

---

#### Waiting For Exit On Bash 4.4

With bash 4.4, process substitutions export their PIDs in `$!`, and these can be `wait`ed for. Thus, you get an alternate way to wait for the FIFO to exit:

```
exec 3> >(tee -a "$logfilename" | jq -sRf json_log_s2o.jq >>"$logfilename.json"); log_pid=$!
```

...and then, later on:

```
wait "$log_pid"
```

as an alternative to the `flock` approach given earlier. Obviously, do this only if you have bash 4.4 available.

Comment: Looks like in "Avoiding FIFO Management (Using Bash)" `exec 3>&1` should be before `exec 3> >` otherwise invalid file descriptor ?  And `2>&1` should be after commands not `>&3` otherwise output to console not to pipeline ?

Comment: Still working through the different implementations and testing, more work to do on process substitution to work out where things are going

Comment: @Gabe, ...however, in `>&3 2>&1`, the second `&1` refers to the same file descriptor as `&3`, since redirections are run left-to-right. Thus, we're first making FD 1 a copy of FD 3, then making FD 2 a copy of FD 1 -- meaning that after these operations are run in this order, 1, 2 and 3 are all pointing to the same place.

Comment: @Gabe, as for `exec 3> >(...)`, that creates FD 3 from nothing if it didn't exist already. There's no need for a prior `exec 3>&1`. Literally what's happening is that it's calling `mkfifo()` to create a FIFO pair, and then using `dup2()` or `dup3()` to rename the input side of the pair to FD 3. If there *did* exist an FD 3 before `dup2()` was called, that old one would just be closed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy ...struggling with `writelogs()`, i can invoke the function with `exec 3> >(writelogs "$logfilename")` , however, that creates the .txt log with no stdout, and the .json log, with a null from jq. It seems like with the function is not receiving or the commands are not sending to the function. Where should the commands sit for there output to be processed by the function? after `exec 3> >(writelogs "$logfilename")` ?

Comment: Any chance you're running `exec 3> >(writelogs ...)` more than once? The first time will inherit its original stdout. The second one will inherit the first one as its stdout, and so forth.

Comment: Thank you, found, it was a simple error in my redirect `{ commands } >3& ` sending the output to file called `3` , corrected `{ commands } >&3 ` and now sending as expected to .txt and .json log files. Moving forward with the testing, thanks again, this is really starting to take shape..

Comment: When implementing two functions in the script `writelogarray2object()` and `writelogstring2object()` , the last invocation overwrites the json log, but not the txt log. The function's pipeline commands append for `tee -a` but overwrite for `jq >&4` which seems to explain the log outputs. I tried `>>&4` and `>> &4` for jq but receive a `syntax error near unexpected token &` any suggestions ?

Comment: A file is only truncated on creation or open, not on a later write to the same fd, so `>&4` won't truncate to empty; rather, `exec 4>foo` instead of `exec 4>>foo` will do that. I'd need to see more context to provide a more helpful response.

Comment: ...actually, I'm guessing this is in the context of `exec 4>"${1}.json"`? Make it `exec 4>>"${1}.json"`, then... though a single JSON document is self-contained and can't be appended to without making it invalid; I'm guessing your format is a JSON *stream* instead?

Comment: happy with bash functions and flocks, however, bash 4.4 and pid waits is causing me an issue with exec. This seems fine: `exec 3> >(tee -a $logfilename.txt | jq -Rnf json_log_array2object.jq >> $logfilename.json) `  but the addition of pid wait `& log_pid=$!` to exec and `wait $log_pid` at the end results in an error `line 8: 3: Bad file descriptor`

Comment: ah -- replaced `&` with `;` so command is `exec 3> >(tee -a $logfilename.txt | jq -Rnf json_log_array2object.jq >> $logfilename.json) ; log_pid=$!` with `wait $log_pid` which results in `line : wait: pid is not a child of this shell`

Comment: Can't help you with that one without a reproducer. If you're really running bash 4.4 and put those commands right next to each other, that issue *doesn't* happen. Something happening between point A and point B that puts one process or the other in a subshell isn't something I can debug in a comment thread. If it's something that continues to vex you, I'd suggest asking a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: Will try and diagnose it further on Bash 4.4, but if no luck, will post a new minimal, complete and verifiable answer (thank you for help reference)